# Play WAR command does not delete sources

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

After packaging play application as WAR file `/ROOT/WEB-INF/application/app` contains source code. Do I need to store it ? Why it is not deleted by default, I can see compiled classes in `precompiled` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you have `precompiled` your application, you can exclude **all the JAVA source code** of your application (*the **views** code **should not be excluded***) when you are in production mode.

By default, `play war projectname -o projecname.war` command should include all the source code on your application. But, you can exclude the application's JAVA source code by using this command (Note that I am using Windows OS here):

> `play war projectname --exclude app\controllers:app\models:app\utils:app\jobs -o projectname.war`

Notice, `--exclude` option has value of the directories (relative to your `projectname` folder) you want to exclude and separated by `:` (a colon) when you want to exclude some directories.

Comment: Yes, I think this files should be deleted by default